# search and replace in a sample file

Tags: html, search, sed, awk, find

Hi I have following file

```
      <strong>Ramandand Sagar Krishna part 34</strong> Vasudev comes back 
and girl disappears from Kansa's hand and the first temple she instructs Devs to make at Vindhyachal <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3p3gu?
width=320&#038;theme=none&#038;wmode=transparent">http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3p3gu?width=320&#038;theme=none&#038;wmode=transparent</a> <a 
href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3p3gu_krishna-part-34_shortfilms" 
target="_blank">Krishna Part 34</a> <strong>Ramandand Sagar Krishna part 35</strong> Celebrations at Yashoda's house and Vasudev Devki freed from jail <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3p3sg?width=320&#038;theme=none&#038;wmode=transparent">
http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3p3sg?width=320&#038;theme=none&#038;wmode=transparent</a> <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3p3sg_krishna-part-35_shortfilms" target="_blank">Krishna Part 35</a> <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x66a71_krishna-143_shortfilms" target="_blank">Krishna 143</a></em></div>
```

In above file I want to replace

any HTML which is of following kind

```
<a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x5ftx3?width=320">http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x5ftx3?width=320</a>
```

the keyword is any HTML tag having `wmode=transparent` or `width=320` should be replaced with a blank space.Is there an easy way to do so?There are many HTML tags like
`<a href=""> </a>` which do not have `wmode=transparent` in their lines.
The file above posted is very very big approximately 30K lines are there in HTML so I have posted only relevant lines.
I am on a Ubuntu system.

Comment: There's no simple way to do this reliably with sed, because [parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) with regex isn't a good idea.

Comment: If you hover over the tags you have assigned to your question, you'll notice, for the worst case example, that `search-and-replace` has 3 followers. I bet html has more followers than that. The goal of course is to get as many knowledgeable people looking at your question as possible. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As Sorpigal has pointed out, there is no simple answer to solve this. If your willing to destroy your line endings you could try my ugly concoction. It might help you:

`cat file.txt | tr -d "\n" | awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i !~ /wmode=transparent|width=320/) printf "%s ", $i} END {print ""}' file.txt | sed -e "s%<a <a%<a%g"`

Output:

`<strong>Ramandand Sagar Krishna part 34</strong> Vasudev comes back and girl disappears from Kansa's hand and the first temple she instructs Devs to make at Vindhyachal <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3p3gu? <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3p3gu_krishna-part-34_shortfilms" target="_blank">Krishna Part 34</a> <strong>Ramandand Sagar Krishna part 35</strong> Celebrations at Yashoda's house and Vasudev Devki freed from jail <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3p3sg_krishna-part-35_shortfilms" target="_blank">Krishna Part 35</a> <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x66a71_krishna-143_shortfilms" target="_blank">Krishna 143</a></em></div>`

I'm sure this one-liner could be improved in some way. If you do find this useful, you may then want to split the output on a boundary to tidy things up. `Sed` can be good for this.

Answer (score 0):

here is a [link](http://www.linuxask.com/questions/replace-multiple-strings-using-sed) where you can found answer for your question.

in your case you have to create a script file for sed like

> s/wmode=transparent//g
>   s/width=320//g

and running something like that:

> sed -f replace_file in.txt > out.txt

i hope it's helpful for you.

have a nice day

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. He wants to identify a tags that have wmode=transparent or width=320, then remove *the entire tag*, not just those parts. Since there's no guarantee each tag is on its own line `sed` is particularly inappropriate.